# Force of baseball bat given force of ball and recoil distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, conservation-laws

Say I swing a baseball bat and hit a ball. The ball is moving at 60 miles per hour and impacts the baseball bat squarely at that speed. The ball has moved twenty feet before impacting the bat. The baseball bat recoils two inches, and the ball is now moving at 55 miles per hour. Given this information, is there any way I can calculate the amount of force with which the bat struck the ball?

Comment: yep, but you'll need the mass of the ball

Comment: No.   You need to know the duration of the collision.

Comment: What is " and impacts the baseball bat squarely at that speed. "?

Answer (score 1):

As force given by an impulse is given by

> $N \times$ (change in time) = $m(v-u)$
>
> $N$ = $m(v-u)$/(change in time)

Hence you need the recoil time of bat and mass of ball to calculate the force given to the ball by bat.

Comment: If the recoil distance given for the bat is the distance over which the ball changes its velocity then you can calculate the recoil time.